# elastic search error 503 MasterNotDiscoveredException while inserting data

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search in a ubuntu based system. 
after successfull installation when i am trying to add an index into ES

> curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/tutorial/helloworld/1' -d '{
>   "message": "Hello World!" }'

i am getting an error

> {"error":"MasterNotDiscoveredException[waited for [1m]]","status":503}

I found few solution in stakoverflow, but it did not work for me and as i am new to this community so i can not add comment to the answer.
Can anyone please help me find out how to solve this.

Comment: What solutions did you try? Also please share the relevant settings from your configuration.

Comment: I have added 
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false as suggested by one of the member.